# Split a large dataframe into a list of dataframes based on values of row of multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large time-series dataframe (`df`) in which the columns `Year#`, `Month#`, `Week#` are derived from the `Date` column.

Question, how to accomplish the following:

1. For all rows which have the same `Year#`, `Month#` and `Week#`, I would like to extract the rows of `df` into a new dataframe `df_subsetx` as shown in attached photo.
2. I would like to compile all these subset dataframes as a 'list of dataframes'

PS- do chime in if there is a better way to handle multiple dataframes than making them 'list of dataframes'

[image]

Comment: Use dictionary of dataframes.  `dict_df = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Year#', 'Month#', 'Day#'])))`

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Week'])`, or `df.groupby('Date')`]

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works good in creating a dictionary of dataframes. However, if I try to perform any numeric calculations on any one subset dataframe, I see that the numbers in any column are treated as string, not as float. For example, in this code here (pasted in my next comment), I try to derive column `New` by adding column `Open` (say value 214.1) and `Close` (value 222.6) but instead of addition I get `New` column as 214.1222.6 .

Comment: `dict_df = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Week'])))`
`for item in dict_df.keys():`
    `dict_df[item]['New'] = dict_df[item]['Open'] + dict_df[item]['Close']`
    `print((dict_df[item]))`

Comment: `df.groupby()` doesn't change the type of the columns. So I'd guess that you couldn't do those operations before splitting into sub-dataframes?

Comment: @Timus I am wondering if `dict` or `tuple` is causing the type to change. You are correct, I cannot do the operations until I split the df into sub-df(s).

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you cannot do the operations before then you have to cast the columns into the right format at the beginning (with something like `df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']] = df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']].astype(float)` etc.)